# What Genre is Dark Souls III?

Tags: terminology, dark-souls-3

Dark Souls III is an online game that follows a single player through a set storyline, but because it is also online I can't decide if it's an MMORPG or something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dark soul is **NOT** a MMORPG, it is simply a fantasy rpg action game that can also be played online.

This quote from wikipedia will help you understand what a MMORPG actually is:

> MMORPGs are distinguished from single-player or small multi-player
>   online RPGs by the number of players able to interact together, and by
>   the game's persistent world (usually hosted by the game's publisher),
>   which continues to exist and evolve while the player is offline and
>   away from the game.